# What does "-log" stand for in MySQL version?

Tags: mysql

When I query the version of my MySQL server (`SELECT VERSION()`) it returns  "5.7.16-log". What does that "-log" stand for?

It's the standard download of the community edition.

Comment: If it's so obvious that people downvote it, why not answer it? Thank's

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I would guess that this is downvoted because someone thought your question was not a question about programming. Stack Overflow wants to be a site only for *specific* programming problems.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_version says:

> - version
>
>   The version number for the server. The value might also include a suffix indicating server build or configuration information. `-log` indicates that one or more of the general log, slow query log, or binary log are enabled. `-debug` indicates that the server was built with debugging support enabled.

I think it's weird that they decided to mash together those three indicators of the runtime configuration, but it probably dates back to very early days of MySQL. Perhaps at the time it was easier to append strings to the version variable than to introduce multiple indicator variables.

Comment: It's wierd that they thought configuration information had anything to do with the version number whatsoever.